# Why is $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + t(y-x)) - f(x)}{t} = \nabla f(x)^T\cdot (y-x)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization

### What I want to understand

I am trying to understand why the following holds:

$$\lim_{t \to 0}  \frac{f(x + t(y-x)) - f(x)}{t} = \nabla f(x)^T\cdot (y-x)$$

with $f: \mathbb{R}^p \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^p$, $t \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Also I am using the following definition of the gradient:

$\nabla{f(x)} = \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x) & 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x) &
\dots &
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p}(x)
\end{bmatrix}^\intercal$

with $x_i$ being the $i$-th element of $x$.

### Why I want to understand it

It is used when proving that a convex function always lies above its tangent line ([see p. 5-6 of this example if you want](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Eaaa/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec7_gh.pdf))

### What I know

The solution probably has something to do with the definition of the derivative as the limit of a difference quotient:

$$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}  \frac{g(z + \Delta z) - g(z)}{\Delta z} = g'(z)$$

With $z, \Delta z \in \mathbb{R}$, and $g: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$

However, I do not understand exactly how (or if) I can use this to arrive at this higher dimensional limit at the top of my question from this definition (or what additional information I need)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your limits are probably at zero not $\infty$ and it may also be $\nabla f(x)^T$ rather than $\nabla f(x)^\prime$. Can you review carefully your question?

Comment: Thanks for letting m know. The limits should go to zero. I meant a transpose with $\nabla f(x)'$ but changed it to $\nabla f(x)^T$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: It is not clear to me what space the $x$ and $y$ belong to. I guess they must be real because you write $x+t$, but then the gradient notations seem superfluous, and a vanilla derivative would suffice.

Comment: Use the chain rule for a quick solution: define $\gamma(t)=x+t(y-x)$. Then your limit is really asking what is $(f\circ \gamma)'(0)$. And the answer is $(\nabla f)(\gamma(0))\cdot \gamma'(0)=\nabla f(x)\cdot (y-x)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think that is what I need, thank you. I just don't 100% understand how my limit $\frac{f(\gamma(t)) - f(x)}{t}$ is the same as $(f \circ \gamma)'(0)$.

Comment: @G.Fougeron Thank you for your comment. I realized I wrote it very sloppily even though I thought I was being careful. I edited the question so that the space that the variables belong to is clear (I think).

Comment: plug in the definitions carefully. What is $f(\gamma(t))$, what is $f(\gamma(0))$? How is $(f\circ\gamma)'(0)$ defined?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you very much, I got it now. If you paste your original comment as an answer i will accept it :)

Comment: The problem looks like it is still here : what is $\Delta x$ ? If it is a scalar, then you cannot add it to $x$. If it is a vector, then you cannot divide by it.

Comment: Okay, I had naively extended the definition of a derivative as the limit of a difference quotient to higher dimensions in a way that simply made no sense, as you pointed out. I corrected that now so I at least do not confuse people who stumble upon my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer so as to not have too many comments.

Thanks for editing your questions several times. It now (as far as I can tell) makes perfect mathematical sense, although there is still a missing link: you did not give a definition of the gradient.

I know I'm being very annoying, but there is a reason for that: the expression of the gradient in your question can actually itself be taken as a definition of the gradient. This is called the Gâteaux derivative of a function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative).

Any answer to you question needs to know what definition you are considering, of course.

Best,

EDIT :

Thanks for adding the gradient definition. Note that your definition can be rephrased as :
$$ (\nabla f)_i(x) = \nabla ^T f(x)\cdot e_i = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) = \frac{d}{dt} f(x+t*e_i) = \lim_{t->0} \frac{f(x+t*e_i) - f(x)}{t} $$
Where $(e_i)$ is the base in which you defined the coordinates.

So that at list when $y-x$ is one of the basis vectors, you have your answer.
Now if you write $ z = y-x = \sum z_i* e_i$, and use the chain rule, you will get your result.

Comment: Thanks. No problem. I takes a trained eye to see a lot of the mistakes/omissions I made so thank you for pointing them out to me. I want to keep the question clear for people who stumble upon it in the future.

Comment: Hey, I edited my answer to actually answer the question :-)